# ember ajax idicator in model

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have some model in ember routing.

```
model() {
    return this.get('store').query('orders', {})
}
```

Also i have adapter, which work send ajax.

model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    login:  DS.attr(),
    pass: DS.attr(),
    smsDisabled: DS.attr(),
    loader_btn: DS.attr(),
    me: DS.attr()

});
```

How change or add loader flag?
How change indicator?

P.S. How to lead to this species:

```
{{#if loader}} //how write it in template?
   <img src="ajax_loader.png" />
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `currentlyLoading` flag or any model properties specific to loading.  You just define corresponding loading template, suppose if you want to show loading for application route, then define `application-loading.hbs`, inside you can write `<img src="ajax_loader.png" />`. that's it remaining thing Ember will take care of it. I [created ember -twiddle which demonstrates two approach](https://ember-twiddle.com/aaf2fb3d38e19705b716da5e46e7e8a9?openFiles=templates.application-loading.hbs%2C&route=%2F%3Fsearch%3Da)
1.using the loading template.
2.Using loading event and defining the controller property.

Comment: thank you for answer, kumkanillam.  I will use from you example

Answer (score 1):

You use the [loading substrate](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/).

While the router waits for the model, you can define a loading template for the loading indicator.

Comment: Thankyou for anwser. I understood i have to write `loading` action in route. And change `currentlyLoading`. And in model i can delete  flag  `loader`, then in template i have to write `if currentlyLoading`. It's rigth way?